# How to suppress talkback programmatically?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Is there any way to make talkback to suppress when I open my application and resume when I stop my Application?

Comment: No, this is by design.

Answer (score 0):

While typically you cannot toggle TalkBack from your app, it is possible if the user grants your app the "write secure settings" system permission from adb, since you can directly modify the flags that indicate to the system which accessibility services are enabled.

See this answer of a similar question for full details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44461236/494879